# Magento get dropdown attribute value with php

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I've got another Magento problem.
I'm trying to sort all active products into new categories, which takes up lots of time. So now I wanted to export the products and do it a little faster, but the Magento export function doesn't really do it for me since it doesn't display the right values in the right columns when exported to csv.

So I'm using this php-script I found here on StackOverflow and it seems to be working great. But I'm trying to get the values from 2 dropdown attributes we created and I can't seem to get it right unfortunately.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//optional for products only visible in catalog     and search
$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku", "z_typ", "z_bereich", "category_ids");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,";");
foreach ($products as $product){
$sku = $product->getSku();
$z_typ = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('z_typ')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
$z_bereich = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('z_bereich')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
$categoryIds = implode(',', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
fputcsv($fp, array($sku, $z_typ, $z_bereich, $categoryIds), ";");
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

This only returns "NO" for the two attributes. I also tried to following, which leaves both columns empty:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//optional for products only visible in catalog     and search
$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku", "z_typ", "z_bereich", "category_ids");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,";");
foreach ($products as $product){
$sku = $product->getSku();
$z_typ = $product->getAttributeText('z_typ');
$z_bereich = $product->getAttributeText('z_bereich');
$categoryIds = implode(',', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
fputcsv($fp, array($sku, $z_typ, $z_bereich, $categoryIds), ";");
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error myself...

Forgot to load the two attributes into the $products array, so it couldn't possibly display them.

Thanks for the help anyways :)

For anyone who wants to use this, here's the correct code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('z_typ');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('z_bereich');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//optional for products only visible in catalog and search
$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku", "z_typ", "z_bereich", "category_ids");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,";");
foreach ($products as $product){
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
    $z_typ = $attributes['z_typ']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    $z_bereich = $attributes['z_bereich']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    $categoryIds = implode(',', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
    fputcsv($fp, array($sku, $z_typ, $z_bereich, $categoryIds), ";");
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```